# JavaScript file is not updated in ASP.net website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm developing a web application. In that, I used a Javascript file for validation.
It worked fine but now I made some changes in the javascript file. 
I got the old alert message only. 
But in that Javascript file, I didn't have the alert message.
Here is my old js and new js.

new Javascript:

```
function ValidateSkill() {
    var skill1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet1');
    var skillrate1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlselfrating');
    var skill2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet2');
    var skillrate2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating1');
    var skill3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet3');
    var skillrate3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating2');
    var skill4 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet4');
    var skillrate4 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating3');
    var skill5 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet5');
    var skillrate5 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating4');
    var skill6 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet6');
    var skillrate6 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating5');

    var count = 0;


    if (skill1.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate1.selectedIndex == 0) {

            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate1.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill2.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate2.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate2.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill3.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate3.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate3.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill4.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate4.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate4.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill5.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate5.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate5.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }


    if (skill6.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate6.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate6.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        alert('Please enter atleast one Skill Set');
        skill1.focus();
        return false;
    }


    return ValidateUnqiue();

}
function ValidateUnqiue() {

    var skill1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet1');
    var skill2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet2');
    var skill3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet3');
    var skill4 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet4');
    var skill5 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet5');
    var skill6 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet6');
    var count = 0;

    if (skill1.value != "") {
        count++;

    }
    if (skill2.value != "") {
        count++;
    }
    if (skill3.value != "") {
        count++;
    }
    if (skill4.value != "") {
        count++;
    }
    if (skill5.value != "") {
        count++;
    }
    if (skill6.value != "") {
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        alert('enter altleast one skill set');
        return false;
    }

    var skillarr = new Array();
    skillarr[skillarr.length] = skill1.value;
    skillarr[skillarr.length] = skill2.value;
    skillarr[skillarr.length] = skill3.value;
    skillarr[skillarr.length] = skill4.value;
    skillarr[skillarr.length] = skill5.value;
    skillarr[skillarr.length] = skill6.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < skillarr.length; i++) {

        for (var j = i + 1; j < skillarr.length; j++) {


            if (skillarr[i] != "" && skillarr[j] != "") {


                if (skillarr[i] == skillarr[j]) {
                    alert("Don't enter the same skill");
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }

    }
    return true;

}
```

old JavaScript

```
function Validate() {
    var skill1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet1');
    var skillrate1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlselfrating');
    var skill2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet2');
    var skillrate2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating1');
    var skill3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet3');
    var skillrate3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating2');
    var skill4 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet4');
    var skillrate4 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating3');
    var skill5 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet5');
    var skillrate5 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating4');
    var skill6 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet6');
    var skillrate6 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSelfrating5');

    var count = 0;


    if (skill1.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate1.selectedIndex == 0) {

            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate1.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill2.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate2.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate2.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill3.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate3.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate3.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill4.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate4.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate4.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    if (skill5.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate5.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate5.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }


    if (skill6.value != "") {
        count++;
        if (skillrate6.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the Self rating');
            skillrate6.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        alert('Please enter atleast one Skill Set');
        skill1.focus();
        return false;
    }


    return ValidateUnqiue();

}
function ValidateUnqiue() {

    var skill1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet1');
    var skill2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet2');
    var skill3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet3');
    var skill4 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet4');
    var skill5 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet5');
    var skill6 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtbxSkillSet6');

    if (skill1.value == skill2.value || skill1.value == skill3.value || skill1.value == skill4.value || skill1.value == skill5.value || skill1.value == skill6.value) {
        alert('Do not enter the same skill set more than once');
        return false;
    }
    if (skill2.value == skill1.value || skill2.value == skill3.value || skill2.value == skill4.value || skill2.value == skill5.value || skill2.value == skill6.value) {
        alert('Do not enter the same skill set more than once');
        return false;
    }
    if (skill3.value == skill1.value || skill3.value == skill2.value || skill3.value == skill4.value || skill3.value == skill5.value || skill3.value == skill6.value) {
        alert('Do not enter the same skill set more than once');
        return false;
    }
    if (skill4.value == skill1.value || skill4.value == skill3.value || skill4.value == skill2.value || skill4.value == skill5.value || skill4.value == skill6.value) {
        alert('Do not enter the same skill set more than once');
        return false;
    }
    if (skill5.value == skill1.value || skill5.value == skill3.value || skill5.value == skill4.value || skill5.value == skill2.value || skill5.value == skill6.value) {
        alert('Do not enter the same skill set more than once');
        return false;
    }
    if (skill6.value == skill1.value || skill6.value == skill3.value || skill6.value == skill4.value || skill6.value == skill5.value || skill6.value == skill2.value) {
        alert('Do not enter the same skill set more than once');
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Did you build the solution and website?

Comment: yeah i build the solution

Comment: Delete your browser history and then try...

Comment: yeah i did that and then i got the alert "Do not enter the same skill set more than once" only but in my new js i don't have this alert

Comment: CTRL-F5 (ie) forces reload of other files (not only html) but also your ISP may cache things, to be sure you better change the name of the file

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are cached like other files, so there may be your browser caching, your proxy caching, etc.. Changing the name of your JS file may be the simplest solution to have it updated for everybody. If in your web app you refer to file myjslibrary.js, then refer to myjslibrary2.js and rename the file.

But probably it is just a local cache problem (your browser), just try to force clear the browser cache: http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/

Comment: yeah i have tried renaming the js file and method in the js file. And then i remove the old sln file and i opened my website and build it. and also i put my project another system & build it. I got the same alert

Comment: @ShankarG Have you tried another (clean) browser? Also make sure there is some modification (just to update the modification date of the file) to the mail html. (if index is not modified some browsers keep not updating other content)

Comment: @ShankarG "clean" browsers? = That had never opened that same site? Otherwise try from another computer.

Comment: @ShankarG you said you renamed the js file, but are you sure you renamed the link to it (that is more important) as in `<script type="text/javascript" src="THE_NEW_SCRIPT_PATH.js"></script>`